# WordPress Network on IIS7/SQL Server - Rewrite Issues

Tags: url-rewriting, multisite, rewrite-rules, iis

I've just installed a fresh WordPress setup on Windows Server 2008 Web R2 (IIS7) with SQL Server Express and WordPress 3.1.

I completed the install successfully and logged into the admin section to start the activation of the WordPress network (using sub-domains). Having edited the wp-config file, I added the code WordPress generated to both wp-config (Network specific) and web.config (Rewrites).

Since adding these changes, each time I try to login to WordPress, I just get loop'd straight back to the login page. I've tried to following so far:

1. Comment out the network specific changes in wp-config and revert the rewrite rules to standard WordPress ones (Didn't work).
2. Checked IIS Admin for any re-writes already in place (None)

Details of wp-config and web.config below:

```
wp-config:
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'svr-web-csrms' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

web.config: http://pastebin.com/8xctXizE

Update: I have had a thought. From reading this [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network):

> Note that per the Settings Requirements you cannot switch from Sub-folder to Sub-domain >when running on 127.0.0.1 or localhost. This can potentially cause an endless loop of >reauth=1 on your root site due to cookie handling.

I may have an issue due to the fact I am using an internal address. I'll set WordPress up with a proper domain and come back.

Comment: Any progress? Could you resolve the issue? If so, please add your solution as answer and mark the question as _answered_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your domain doesn't match the cookie being generated. It may not have anything to do with the IP.

```
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'svr-web-csrms' );
```

I would expect an actual domain or something, like this.

```
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'subdomain.mysite.tld' );
```

I tried to look at your web.config - but it appears that the URL is now broken.